# How can I add variadic args this macro in c and execute more than one action?

Tags: c, error-handling

I am trying write an assert like macro that will check runtime errors. At the very bottom you can find what I have for that macro and some things are not as I expect it to be.

The first thing that does not is function evaluation.
Lets say `someFuntion()` returns an integer and `expr = (someFunction() > 0)`
In this case even if `someFunction()` is greater zero the expression fails.

Secondly I want to be able to execute more than one action. For example, if I pass 2 actions I want two actions to be executed.
I want to be able to pass execute_action_before_exit = `(someFunction2(), someFucntion3())`
and it should execute all the functions before exit. What should I look into acheive this? Or Is it not possible?

The code I have:

```
#ifndef RT_ASSERT_H
#define RT_ASSERT_H

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define rt_assert(expr, file, str, execute_action_before_exit)                                \
  ((void) sizeof ((expr) ? 1 : 0), __extension__ ({                                           \
    if (!expr) {                                                                              \
        fprintf(file, "In file %s:%d, Error: %s\n",__FILE__, __LINE__, str);                  \
        execute_action_before_exit;                                                           \
        fclose(file);                                                                         \
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);                                                                   \
    }                                                                                         \
    }))
```

Usage of current the macro

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "runtime_assert.h"

void someFunction(void) {
   // does some cleaning action or any action
}

void someFunction1(void) {
   // does some cleaning action or any action
}

int main (void) {
    FILE *abort_msg = fopen("exit_msg.txt", "w+");
    if (!abort_msg) {
        printf("Failed to create/open exit_msg.txt\n");
        getchar();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    FILE *foo = fopen("FOO.txt", "r");
    rt_assert((foo), abort_msg, "Failed of open file -->possibly missing<--", (someFunction()));

    fclose(abort_msg);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
```

How I want to modify the use

```
rt_assert(                                               \
(foo),                                                   \
abort_msg, "Failed of open file -->possibly missing<--", \
(someFunction(),someFunction1())                         \
);
```

Comment: Could you also give an example of what the usage of this macro should look like?

Comment: Sorry it took me some time, I got busy with something else. I updated it now. if  you need more clarification pls let me know

Comment: Ok that makes sense for your second problem (multiple functions), but I don't understand your first one ("first thing that does not is function evaluation").

Comment: The 1st problem is that I had a function that returns an integer which is greater than 0. Lets call the function `x()`. so, if i do `rt_assert( x() > 0 , rest of the arguments)`. The assert fails even though it should not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#define rt_assert(expr, file, str, ...)\
  ((void) sizeof ((expr) ? 1 : 0), __extension__ ({\
    if (!(expr)) {\
        fprintf((file), "In file %s:%d, Error: %s\n",__FILE__, __LINE__, (str));\
        __VA_ARGS__;\
        fclose(file);\
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);\
    }\
    }))
```

I've made two changes here:

(1) used `!(expr)` instead of `!expr`. This fixes the first problem you were having, that the expressions passed in were being evaluated wrong. Remember, macros are basically just copy-pasting, so when you do `rt_assert( x() > 0 , rest of the arguments)`, this gets "pasted" into the if statement as `if (!x() > 0) ...`, which will not be evaluated as you expect. What you want is `if (!(x() > 0)) ...`, which is now correctly handled. I've done the same for the other parameters.

(2) I've changed the macro to be variadic, so you can pass any number of arguments to it. The syntax for this is `...` when declaring the macro, and `__VA_ARGS__` to use the variadic arguments. (Search "Variadic Macros" to find more info here.)

Comment: It works for everything. Thank you again. I tested it thoroughly. I saw variadic macros and __VA_ARGS__ but everyone in their example using it with printf and it led me to believe that its related to the format string.